# XSD schema on some kind of dynamic XML structure

Tags: xml, xsd

I have list of mapping XML documents which is basically translations from one language to other. This is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root lang="en,fr">
    <item name="error_1">
        <en><![CDATA[User name does not exist.]]></en>
        <fr><![CDATA[Nom d'utilisateur n'existe pas.]]></fr>
    </item>
    <item name="error_2">
        <en><![CDATA[One or both path parameters have not defined.]]></en>
        <fr><![CDATA[Un ou deux paramètres de trajet ne sont pas définies.]]></fr>
    </item>
</root>
```

I need to write XSD on this type of files if it is possible.
As I see here is some type of complicity with elements because language elements is dynamic type base on attribute ***lang*** of the **root** element.
Language value is base on ISO 639-1 standard, separated by comma and could be one or more. In this case each item set must have the same element included. Default ***lang*** attribute has single value "en" and element **item** only one sub-element **en**. It is looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root lang="en">
    <item name="error_1">
        <en><![CDATA[User name does not exist.]]></en>
    </item>
    <item name="error_2">
        <en><![CDATA[One or both path parameters have not defined.]]></en>
    </item>
</root>
```

I need some solution, advice. Is this task achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3C schema doesn't allow you to express those sort of conditional constraints.

**[Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) is an ISO standard that was designed for this sort of validation.**

As an aside, if you made the `@lang` [NMTOKENS](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xml-2e-20000814#NT-Nmtokens) other systems reading the schema would know how to handle it.  Comma separated values requires additional custom parsing logic to understand that there are multiple values in that attribute value.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is suppose to be at W3C schema format. Probably, I have to defined list of languages which will be supported. Looks like I don't have other options at W3C field.

Answer (score 0):

No, XML Schema cannot constrain elements based on the value of attributes.

Comment: It was some type of trouble feeling for this task. Looks like you confirmed it.